# getting Jmeter to report failure on error

Tags: jmeter

Currently experimenting with swapping out a couple of powershell warm up commands for our web app to use jmeter test plans.  The features look much improved and execute significantly quicker.

I am executing the test plans using the non-gui mode through octopus deploy.  How can i get the task to quit reporting failure when it encounters a http error status code?  I need the job to report as failure on encountering an error and mark the task as complete if any of my hosts return anything other than a http success code?

We are using DFS across 20+ hosts and the existing powershell works as a good check that everything has replicated and working before we bring the new instances live (using blue/green deployment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add [JSR223 Assertion](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Assertion) to your Test Plan at the same level as your HTTP Request samplers (or according to [JMeter Scoping Rules](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/UserManual/ScopingRules) if you want to apply them to certain requests only)
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   if ((prev.getResponseCode() as int) > 399) {
       System.out.println('HTTP status code for URL: ' + prev.getUrlAsString() + ' was ' + prev.getResponseCode())
       System.exit(-1)
   }
   ```
3. That's it, when you run your test and get HTTP Status code 400 or higher - the JSR223 Assertion will terminate the test and return non-zero [exit status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status)

   [image]

   More information: [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial)

Comment: Just had a go but not seeing the error message returning when the site is giving a 503 error

Comment: Here's my config [link](https://imgur.com/a/2KvTsJd)  Tried moving the jsr223 task around but didn't look to make a difference.  Still seeing the job giving the same finish - https://imgur.com/a/eg8DjZ1

Comment: Looks to be working now, still some errors but looks good and works! https://imgur.com/a/QnX5Y2h i'd added it as a sampler and not an assertion at first.  Changed it and all good.  Thanks for help and much appreciated!!

Comment: Not quite behaving as expected in Octopus Deploy and not exiting/reporting failure but making progress - https://imgur.com/a/GEYvpaZ

Comment: The problem I'm running into is that it's asking for a keypress.  When i run the test plan from powershell in Octopus Deploy the task doesn't finish as looks to be waiting for a keypress.  Also get similar behaviour running the command from the powershell ISE, doesn't complete and needs me to break the command.  Any ideas as almost there with it

Comment: I have no idea why my comment was deleted, I was recommending launching JMeter as `java -jar ApacheJMeter.jar` as `jmeter.bat` shell script is written in a manner which is not friendly for scripting.

Comment: That's done the job.  Reporting as ok now and behaving as expected. Getting a warning from the script through - any ideas? WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred 
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields (file:/D:/apache-jmeter-5.1/lib/xstream-1.4.11.jar) to field java.util.TreeMap.comparator 
Error
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields 
Error
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations 
Error