# How do I read and compare jmeter results in CI/CD pipeline

Tags: jmeter, gitlab-ci, performance-testing

I don't have any experience in non functional testing. But I have just written a jmeter test and hooked up in gitlab ci. I am generating a testresults.jtl and added in artifacts.

But I am not sure how to read the results and how to compare it with the previous results to see or get notified if there are any changes in performance.

What should I do?

Comment: you can also JSR223 it is coming from this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/55120102/18201866

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using [Taurus tool](https://gettaurus.org/) which:

1. Has [JUnit XML Reporter](https://gettaurus.org/docs/Reporting/#JUnit-XML-Reporter) producing [JUnit-style](https://junit.org/junit5/) XML result files which can be ["understood" by GitLab CI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/unit_test_reports.html)
2. Has [Pass/Fail Criteria subsystem](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/running-your-load-tests-with-pass-fail-criteria-a-guide) where you can specify the error thresholds, if i.e. response time will be higher than the defined value Taurus will stop with non-zero [exit status code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status) so GitLab automatically will fail the build on getting non-zero exit code.